# Fit an image inside a rectangle in easelJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs

I am new to easelJS and I was trying to fit an image inside a rectangle. I am able to set the x,y but not the width and height. What is the right approach?

```
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    var layoutWidth = 0.8 * stage.canvas.width;
    var layoutHeight = 0.6 * stage.canvas.height;
    var layoutRect = new createjs.Shape();
    layoutRect.graphics.beginStroke("black").drawRect((stage.canvas.width - layoutWidth) / 2, (stage.canvas.height - layoutHeight) / 2, layoutWidth, layoutHeight);
    var imageContainer = new createjs.Shape();
    imageContainer.graphics.beginStroke("black").drawRect((stage.canvas.width - layoutWidth) / 2 + (layoutWidth - 0.25 * layoutWidth) / 2, (stage.canvas.height - layoutHeight) / 2 + 0.1 * layoutHeight, 0.25 * layoutWidth, 0.25 * layoutWidth);
    var image = new createjs.Bitmap("pizza.jpg");
    image.x = (stage.canvas.width - layoutWidth) / 2 + (layoutWidth - 0.25 * layoutWidth) / 2;
    image.y = (stage.canvas.height - layoutHeight) / 2 + 0.1 * layoutHeight;
    stage.addChild(layoutRect, imageContainer, image);
    stage.update();
```

I want to place the image inside image container.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to fit the image in a rectangle you need to get the width and height of the image, but you can't do that directly if the image isn't loaded.

What you can do is create the image object manually, then use it as the first parameter of `createjs.Bitmap`.

In this way you're already able to resize the image. I updated this example basing in @Lanny fiddle in comments, instead of updating **`imageobj`** size, I'm setting the scale of **`image`** as **`scale`**, and I put the image in the center point of the image container. I was not too familiar with EaselJS, so I've not tried updating the image scale before.

```
var containerX = (stage.canvas.width - layoutWidth) / 2,
    containerY = (stage.canvas.height - layoutHeight) / 2;

var image,
    imageobj = new Image;

imageobj.onload = function() {
    var containerBounds = imageContainer.getTransformedBounds();

    var xratio = layoutWidth / this.width,
        yratio = layoutHeight / this.height;

    var scale = Math.min(xratio, yratio);

    image = new createjs.Bitmap(imageobj);
    image.scaleX =
    image.scaleY = scale;
    image.x = containerX + ((imageobj.width / 2) * scale);
    image.y = containerY + ((imageobj.height / 2) * scale);
};

imageobj.src = "pizza.jpg";
```

Comment: This has the right idea, but I would recommend instead scaling the Bitmap, and not the source image. This gives you more control of the size when things change, and you can use the original size of the image each time. Here is an updated spike which toggles between a "fit" and "fill" scale. Instead of using a containerBounds, it just scales and centers in the Canvas element. http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/7mt9nzbp/